# How to convert UnicodeEncoding output into plain string?

Tags: vb.net, delphi, character-encoding

Hi I'm currently converting a delphi code into .net
they have this encryption in their database I have decrypted but the problem is 
the output  is in byte array.

heres what I've done so far

```
Private Function EnDeCrypt(ByVal Value As String) As String

    Dim transformed = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Value).Select( _
        Function(item) Not item)
    Return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(transformed.ToArray())

End Function
```

Result : º»¯³¶½ = e d p l i b(unprintable chars)

my problem is how to convert the output to  string
Suggestions and help are greatly appreciated

Comment: What are the hex values of the raw bytes returned by `transformed.ToArray()` before you call `GetString()`? By using `Encoding.Unicode`, your code is assuming the bytes are UTF-16 encoded, and that is obviously not the case, so you need to use a different `Encoding`, unless your query is just returning garbage to begin with. I am not familiar with LINQ, can you explain what the query is trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: This is the encoding issue that I raised in your last question. The questions I asked then are still valid I suspect.

Comment: @remy the LINQ code just performs bitwise negation on the input. In fact I wrote that code. I warned OP that it would produce invalid UTF-16 but OP asserted that this was definitely the algorithm that was needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that if your encode algorithm really is bitwise negation of a UTF-16 string, then you cannot print the output. The algorithm produces un-printable output.

You could add an extra encoding to base64 at display time to make the negated bytes, transformed in your code, displayable.

If you want more precise help I think you will need to explain the context and what your motivations are.

Comment: What are you going on about David, is this some weird C# or Delphi oddity that I don't know about?

Comment: @owlstead what don't you understand?

Comment: What has unicode to do with byte negation? Is this some implementation specific detail of either one of the API's?

Comment: The code in the question converts the string into a UTF-16 encoded byte array and then performs bitwise negation. That's what I'm talking about. The previous question gives you some extra context.

Comment: @owlstead if you just generate some random sequence of bytes it may not be a valid unicode string.

Comment: @MarkJ : yes, thank you, that is clear to me, I was just missing some context given in the previous question